# How to send keystrokes to application in Blue Prism?

Tags: automation, blueprism

In a HTML application I need to put text and press Enter key in order to perform search task. There is no alternate of pressing Enter key to search text. In Blue prism I couldn't find way of sending Enter key (or any other hotkey) after writing text to search element.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Navigate stage in business object/process
2. Double click on navigate stage
3. Select root app element and drag & drop element to his position and Actions combobox , select Global Send Keys
4. Type `{ENTER}` in right hand side
5. Reset business object
6. Run application

Answer (score 1):

Navigate Stage, use the main app element in the given list, drag and drop in his position, and in Actions comboBox, select Global Send Keys.

Go down, in Text input, write "{ENTER}" and Done.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAVIGATE, in it use your Element(field, where you put your text) and in Action dropbox you will have "Send Key" or "Global Send Key". Choose one of those and at the bottom of Navigate window there will be Input section where you can type in(as a text) button which you need: "Enter"